# Bootstrap Dropdown Anchor Href value for non-navigational links?

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

On the official [Bootstrap Dropdown page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/components/dropdowns/), it suggests having a href attribute for the dropdown links. Rather than using this dropdown menu for navigation, I want to use it as an action menu in a React app, like copying text:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Copy Text</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

In this context, what should be the href value? It seems that clicking on the Copy Text link also updates the browser's location bar URL. Does using a click listener and adding `event.preventDefault()` in it applicable here?

How should I construct the href value in the case of JS action menu while maintaining the accessibility?